# How to show WebPage document into XUL elemento?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am doing a Firefox addon and I've a button on my navigation bar. If I click on my button, I drill down a panel with elements like a label, buttons etc. I'd like **to show a webpage** (ex: google.com) in this panel.

Thank you 4 your answer,
Diego.

Answer (score 1):

You can put an IFRAME inside your panel and show it there:

### In your XUL:

```
<vbox id="iframeContainerContainer" align="top">
    <iframe id="myframe" width="100" height="100"/>
</vbox>
```

### In your JS:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src","http://www.google.com");
```

This is a basic implementation. For more details, see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution for my problem and I have a box with my loaded webpage in this way:

```
 <vbox id="testPanel" align="top" width="500" height="500">
<groupbox flex="1">
 <caption label="Myweb"/>
 <browser type="content" scrollbars="no" width="500" height="500" src="http://www.myweb.com" flex="1"/>
</groupbox>     
  </vbox>
```

Now **I want to hide the scroll bars which appear in my browser xul element**. It is because I just wanna show a part of my site 500x500. I don't know what propierty I should set off :S

THank you,
DIego